# Ноль или нуль?

Tags: предложение

Как правильно написать:

на ноль не делится или на нуль не делится?

Comment: @Танюшка, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Дело в том,что вчера учительница исправила ребёнка,ноль на нуль,и слово делится-на делиться!!!

Comment: Ну, учительница не права... А насчет "делиться" - надо привести точную фразу.
Например, "ни одно число не может делитЬся на нуль [на ноль]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: не делится на ноль, но: равно нулю.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Слова нуль и ноль заимствованы из немецкого языка, но восходят они к латинскому слову со значением «никакое». Слово ноль соответствует краткому произношению латинской буквы u, а слово нуль – ее написанию.

2) Слова ноль и нуль употребляются одинаково часто, но не заменяют друг друга.

3) Слово ноль является основной формой для ударной позиции основы слова, форма нуль в этом случае употребляется крайне редко:

Двенадцать ноль-ноль, дождь стучит за окном. Ноль –  это Вселенная! Начало начал! Еще не было оси координат, а ноль уже был. Без свиты пиарщиков и журналистской обслуги – они ноль без палочки. На сцену – ноль внимания.

Но: абсолютный нуль  - физический термин, функция обращается в нуль - математическая формулировка (форма нуль в ударной позиции как исключение).

4) В безударной позиции слова употребляется только слово нуль, которое фактически является фонетической заменой для слова ноль. Это связано с тем, что для слова ноль обычная в этом случае редукция О/А нежелательна:

Температура –  около нуля градусов.  Сумма моментов сил равняется нулю. Мы почитаем всех нулями, а единицами – себя. В военном искусстве он был нулем абсолютный.  За нулевой отсчет для географической долготы был принят гринвичский меридиан.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Запрета на использование форм "ноль и нуль"  в какой-либо позиции нет, речь идет о частотности употребления: "ноль" ЧАЩЕ применяется в ударной позиции, а "нуль" - ПОЧТИ ВСЕГДА в безударной (в косвенных падежах и в прилагательном "нулевой"). Если речь идет о школе, то надо посмотреть учебники по математике, используемые в данной школе.

К примеру, в Нацкорпусе у "нулевой" - 503 вхождения, а у "нолевой" - 7 вхождений (в основном в старой литературе). У "нулю" - 1073 вхождения, у "нолю" - 9 вхождений.

"На ноль" - 48 вхождений, "на нуль" - 23 вхождения, из них многие относятся к "установке стрелки на нуль" - технический термин. В целом можно сказать, что ударная форма  "нуль" в большей степени характерна для терминологии.

Comment: А может, не нужно мудрить: ударная позиция, безударная... А просто сказать, что в косвенных падежах всегда У? Тем более что это так и есть... А начальная форма – тут узус тиранус рулит, и любое "объяснение" будет задним числом.

И почему это вы отсекаете "деление на нуль"? Нормальный вариант, ошибки нет.

Answer (score 1):

Оба ваши варианта верны. Только "делиТСя".

Answer (score 1):

Существует две формы: ноль и нуль. В терминологическом значении (особенно в косвенных падежах) обычно используется вторая, например: равняется нулю, температура держится на нуле. В устойчивых выражениях встречаются обе формы, ср.:

1. ноль целых, ноль внимания, в двенадцать ноль-ноль;
2. абсолютный нуль, круглый нуль, обратиться в нуль, свести к нулю.

Производное прилагательное обычно образуется от формы *нуль*, например: нулевой меридиан, нулевая отметка.

[Числительные количественные, порядковые, дробные](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/31.htm#%D0%B7_01)